# Imagem não salva no diretorio

Tags: php, imagem

Falaaa galera, bom dia, to com um probleminha simples porem chato, tenho um formulário que são enviadas algumas informações e imagens, e esse formulário é editável, as informações são alteradas perfeitamente, estou tendo problema com a imagem, pelo que parece ela ta alterando, mas só no banco, a pasta de diretório fica vazia, tem como exibir a imagem sem ser pelo diretório? pois quando e enviado o formulário pela primeira vez fica tudo certo a imagem é exibida sem erros, porem quando vou alterar ela nao vai para o diretório. Se alguém puder dar uma ajuda agradeço desde jáaa, VLWWW

**salva_ed.php**

```js
<?php
//inicia conexão com o banco 
include ("conexao.php");
$new_name = "";

 // recebe o codigo do registro 

$iden = isset($_POST['iden'])?$_POST['iden']:""; 

$iden = $_POST ['codigo']; 

$arquivo = isset($_FILES['arquivo'])?$_FILES['arquivo']:""; 
$arquivo = $_FILES ['arquivo']; 

// aqui seria onde ele veifica se existe algo no campo arquivo e o substitui por um valor em branco 
if($arquivo == ""){
    $query =("update eqp set arquivo = '' WHERE codigo='$iden'");
}else{

// aqui seria onde fazia o update da imagem, dando um novo nome e movendo para a pasta de upload 
 if(isset($_FILES['imagem']))
   {
      $sql =  mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM eqp WHERE codigo = '$iden' ");
      $escrever=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão
    $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['imagem']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
    $new_name = $resultado['foto']; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
    $dir ='uploads/'; //Diretório para uploads

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo

   }
$new_name = $_FILES['arquivo']["name"];
$imagem = $new_name;

var_dump($imagem);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($imagem);
echo '</pre>';
    
    
$query=("UPDATE eqp SET arquivo= '$imagem' WHERE codigo='$iden'");

  $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

  // Verifica se o comando foi executado com sucesso
  if(!$result)
    echo "Registro NÃO alterado.";
  else
    echo "Registro Alterado com sucesso.";
}
?>
```

**mensagem final**

```js
string(12) "IMG_6175.JPG"

IMG_6175.JPG

Registro Alterado com sucesso.
```

Comment: Sabe se a pasta está com as permissões configuradas da forma certa? As vezes o arquivo não é gravado pois o sistema não está deixando o código acessar a pasta.

Comment: olá @adrianosmateus valeu pela atenção, cara, desconfiei disso também e dei uma olhada, é esta com as permissão certinhas, pois como disse, quando e enviado sem ser alterada a imagem vai certinho para o diretório e é exibida normalmente.

Comment: Pode postar o código HTML do formulário de envio dos dados?

Comment: assim é como esta o codigo html @adrianosmateus    <form method="post" action="processa1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"><form>
    <div class="form-group">
    
                <input type="submit" class="bnt salvar" value="Enviar"> 
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagem:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <h5>Arquivo em anexo: <font color="#00BFFF">*</font></h5> <input type="file" class= "anexo" name="arquivo">
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>

Comment: Vi que tem uma outra tag <form> depois da abertura do <form method="post" action="processa1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">. Tira essa tag e testa novamente.

Comment: cara, aquela e minha pagina de inicio, esse form que é responsavel pela edição e está assim :              <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='salva_ed.php''>
            <td>Codigo:</td><td> <input type='text' name='codigo' value='"  .   $codigo . "'> </td>  
              
              <td>Arquivo em anexo: <input type='file' class= 'anexo' name='arquivo'> </td>
              
              <br><br>  
           
             </tr>

      <br><br>
      
      <input type='submit' class='bnt salvar' value='Salvar'>

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu entendi o seu problema está apenas em mover o arquivo upado. Tente o seguinte:

```
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

$diretorio = '../nome_da_pasta/'; //define o caminho do diretório
$arquivo = $diretorio . basename($_FILES['arquivo']['nome']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['nome_temporario'], $arquivo)) { //move o arquivo para o diretório
echo '';
}else{
echo 'Não foi possível mover o arquivo.';
 } 

print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: olá, obrigado pela atenção @silvialuize, é exatamente esse o meu problema haha, testei o código que tu me mandou porem sem sucesso, ele não da nenhum erro, mas também  não move o arquivo para a pasta

Comment: Que estranho. Esse arquivo vem de um formulário, certo? Pode me mandar o código do form?

Comment: noobphp, tente colocar no input da imagem isso: accept="image/*"

Comment: ainda não sem sucesso :S respondi a minha própria pergunta com mais partes do código para ajudar no entendimento

Answer (score 0):

consegui mandar para o diretorio, foi so mudar o :

```js
if (isset($_FILES['imagem'])){ 

para:

if (isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){

ficando assim o codigo:

<?php
//inicia conexão com o banco 
include ("conexao.php");
$new_name = "";

 // recebe o codigo do registro 

$iden = isset($_POST['iden'])?$_POST['iden']:""; 

$iden = $_POST ['codigo']; 

$arquivo = isset($_FILES['arquivo'])?$_FILES['arquivo']:""; 
$arquivo = $_FILES ['arquivo']; 

// aqui seria onde ele veifica se existe algo no campo arquivo e o substitui por um valor em branco 
if($arquivo == ""){
$query =("update eqp set arquivo = '' WHERE codigo='$iden'");
}else{

// aqui seria onde fazia o update da imagem, dando um novo nome e movendo para a pasta de upload 
if (isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){
$extensao= strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4));
$novo_nome= md5(time()) . $extensao;
$diretorio= "upload/";

   if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome)){
   echo"sucesso";
   }else{
   echo"nao";
   }

}
$novo_nome = $_FILES['arquivo']["name"];
$imagem = $novo_nome;

var_dump($imagem);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($imagem);
echo '</pre>';


$query=("UPDATE eqp SET arquivo= '$imagem' WHERE codigo='$iden'");

  $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

  // Verifica se o comando foi executado com sucesso
  if(!$result)
echo "Registro NÃO alterado.";
  else
echo "Registro Alterado com sucesso.";
}
?>
```

agora está mandando normalmente para o diretorio e alterando no banco de dados, porem não estou conseguindo exibir essa nova imagem, estou tentando assim :

**cons_.php**

```js
<?php

//inicia a conexao com o banco 

include_once("conexao.php"); 

//filtro para pesquisa por palavra chave 

$filtro = isset($_GET['filtro'])?$_GET['filtro']:"";

//consulta slq
$sql = "SELECT * FROM eqp";
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
$registros = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

?>

<html lang ="pt-br">         

  <head>                      

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Filtro de Busca </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../agoravai/edicao/form_consultate.css">


  </head>


      <body>

         <div class="container">

          <nav>

           <ul class="menu">

                   <li></li>
                 <a href="inicio.php"><li>Inicio</li></a>
                    <a href="filtros.php"><li>Filtros:</li></a>
                    <a href="telalog_ed_cons.php"><li>Editar Dados:</li></a>
                 
                     
                    
                    

                </ul>
                
          </nav>

           <section>

          
              <h1>Consulta por Formularios Enviados Realizada:</h1>
              <br>
              <hr>
               
               

        

               <?php
               
               //verifica os itens do banco e os exibe
                print" <h1>$registros Registros encontrados:</h1>";
               
               while($exebirregistros = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
                   
                    $codigo = $exebirregistros[0];
                  $nome = $exebirregistros[1];
                   $setor =$exebirregistros[2];
                   $equipamento =$exebirregistros[3];
                   $numeroserie =$exebirregistros[4];
                   $numeropatrimonio =$exebirregistros[13];
                   $locais =$exebirregistros[5];
                   $motivo =$exebirregistros[6];
                   $enviando = $exebirregistros[7];
                   $recebendo =$exebirregistros[8];
                   $defeito =$exebirregistros[9];
                   $transporte =$exebirregistros[10];
                   $dataid =$exebirregistros[11];
                   $dataret =$exebirregistros[12];
                    $numeropatrimonio =$exebirregistros[13];
                   $arquivo =$exebirregistros[14];
                   $ordemdeservico =$exebirregistros[15];
                   
//alerme para data de envio e entrega de equipamento
                   
$data_atual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$data_expiracao = new DateTime($dataret);

$intervalo_em_dias = $data_atual->diff($data_expiracao);

echo $intervalo_em_dias->format('<h4>%R%a DIAS PARA VENCER O RETORNO</h4>');
             
                   
           echo (" <table border='2px' cellpacing='15px'>
        
           <tr>
            <td>Codigo: </td>
        <td>Nome:</td>
            <td>Setor:</td>
            <td>Equipamento:</td>
            <td>Anexo N° ".$codigo.":</td>
            <td>Numero de Serie:</td>
            <td>Numero de Patrimonio:</td>
            <td>Local de Envio:</td>
            <td>Motivo Envio:</td>
            <td>Quem esta Enviando:</td>
            <td>Quem esta Recebendo:</td>
            <td>Defeito:</td>
            <td>Meio de Transporte:</td>
            <td>Data ida:</td>
            <td>Data Retorno:</td>
           
          
            </tr> ");      
                    
    echo  ("
    
<tr>

    <td>" . $codigo . " </td><br>
    
    <td>" . $nome . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $setor . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $equipamento . " </td>
    
    <td class= ok >" . "<img src='upload/".$arquivo."'width=50px height=50px /></td>
    
    <td>" . $numeroserie . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $numeropatrimonio . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $locais . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $motivo . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $enviando . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $recebendo . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $defeito . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $transporte . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $dataid . " </td>
    
    <td>" . $dataret . " </td>
    
  
    </tr>
    <td> <a href='ed_cons_.php?codigo=" . $codigo . "'>editar</td>


    
    ")
        ;
                   
              
               }  
               
            
               
               mysqli_close($conexao);
                                
               ?>
              
                <br>


           </section>


         </div>



     </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Falaaaa galera, depois de algum tempo consegui!!!!**

Segue o código para alteração de dados e imagem em um formulario php, vou deixar aqui para se alguem mais enfrentar o  problema...

**consulta_php**

```js
<?php

session_start();
 if (empty($_SESSION['login'])){
   header("Location: index.php");
   die();

    }

include ("conexao.php");
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
?>

<html lang ="pt-br">      
<html>
  <head>                     

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../formularios_rictv/css/estilo.css">

  </head>
    
    
            <body>
                     
                 <nav>

                                           
                                               
                       <ul class="menu">

                                                           <li></li>
                            <a href="../formularios_rictv/inicio.php"><li>Inicio</li></a>
                             <a href="../equipamentos/consultaeqp.php"><li>Consulta</a>
                 

                               </ul>

                   </nav>
    
    
    
              </body>
    

    <body>
    
        
        
        
        <?php

        
        
$iden = isset($_GET['iden'])?$_GET['iden']:"";      

$iden = $_GET ['codigo'];
     
        
$sql = "select * from eqp where codigo = '$iden'";

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

$registros = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
    
    

             $codigo = $linhas ['codigo'];
            
            $nome = $linhas ['nome'];
            $setor = $linhas ['setor'];
            $equipamento = $linhas['equipamento'];
            $numeroserie = $linhas['numeroserie'];
            $numeropatrimonio = $linhas['numeropatrimonio'];
            $locais = $linhas['locais'];
            $motivo = $linhas['motivo'];
            $enviando = $linhas['enviando'];
            $recebendo = $linhas['recebendo'];
            $defeito = $linhas['defeito'];
            $uldefeito = $linhas['uldefeito'];
            $transporte = $linhas['transporte'];
            $dataid = $linhas['dataid'];
            $dataret = $linhas['dataret'];
            $status_eqp = $linhas['status_eqp'];
            $arquivo = $linhas['arquivo'];
   
           
    
    
    
    
        
    
    
    
            echo ("
            
            
            <tr>
            
             <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='salva_ed.php''>
              
              
             
            <td>Codigo:</td><td> <input type='text' name='codigo' value='"  .   $codigo . "'> </td>                 
            
     <br><br>
            
             <td>Setor:</td><td> <input type='text'name='setor'value='" . $setor . "'></td>
             
    
              <br><br>
              
             <td>Equipamento:</td><td> <input type='text'name=''value='" . $equipamento . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
             <td>N° de Serie:</td <td> <input type='text'name=''value='" . $numeroserie . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
            <td>N° Patrimonio:</td> <td> <input type='text'name=''value='" . $numeropatrimonio . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
             <td>Local de Envio:</td><td> <input type='text'name='locais'value='" . $locais. "'></td>
             
             <br><br>
             
             <td>Motivo:</td><td> <input type='text'name='motivo'value='" . $motivo . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
            <td>Quem esta Enviando:</td> <td> <input type='text'name='enviando'value='" . $enviando . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
             <td>Recebendo:</td><td> <input type='text'name='recebendo'value='" . $recebendo . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
             <td> Defeito:</td><td> <input type='text'name='defeito'value='" . $defeito . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
                <td> Ultimo Defeito:</td><td> <input type='text'name='uldefeito'value='" . $uldefeito . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
             <td>Transporte:</td><td> <input type='text'name='transporte'value='" . $transporte . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
             <td>Data Idá:</td><td> <input type='text'name='dataid'value='" . $dataid . "'></td>
              
              <br><br>
              
             <td> Data Retorno:</td><td> <input type='text'name='dataret'value='" . $dataret . "'></td>
                   <br><br>  
                   
                <td>Arquivo em anexo: <input type='file' class= 'anexo' name='arquivo'> </td>
                   <br><br>
                   
                   
                   
             
             <td> Situação Atual :</td><td> <input type='text'name='status_eqp'value='" . $status_eqp . "'></td>
             
            
             
             </tr>

      <br><br>
      
      <input type='submit' class='bnt salvar' value='Salvar'> 
            
  
           
 
 
 
 ");
     
        
        }
       
        ?>
        
        
        
    </body>
    
    
</html>
```

**salva_ed.php**

```js
<?php

session_start();
 if (empty($_SESSION['login'])){
   header("Location: index.php");
   die();

    }

include ("conexao.php");
$login = $_SESSION['login'];      
            $codigo = $_POST ['codigo'];
            $login = $_SESSION ['login'];
            $setor = $_POST ['setor'];
            $locais = $_POST['locais'];
            $motivo = $_POST['motivo'];
            $enviando = $_POST['enviando'];
            $recebendo = $_POST['recebendo'];
            $defeito = $_POST['defeito'];
            $uldefeito = $_POST['uldefeito'];
            $transporte = $_POST['transporte'];
            $dataid = $_POST['dataid'];
            $dataret = $_POST['dataret'];
            $status_eqp = $_POST['status_eqp'];
$iden = isset($_POST['iden'])?$_POST['iden']:""; 

$iden = $_POST ['codigo']; 

$arquivo = isset($_FILES['arquivo'])?$_FILES['arquivo']:""; 
$arquivo = $_FILES ['arquivo']; 

if($arquivo == ""){
    $query =("update eqp set arquivo = '' WHERE codigo='$iden'");
}else{

// aqui seria onde fazia o update da imagem, dando um novo nome e movendo para a pasta de upload 
if (isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){
    $extensao= strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4));
    $novo_nome= md5(time()) . $extensao;
    $diretorio= "upload/";
    
   if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome)){
       echo"sucesso";
   }else{
       echo"nao";
   }
    
var_dump($novo_nome);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($novo_nome);
echo '</pre>';
    
}
}

$sql = "UPDATE eqp SET  codigo= '$codigo' , setor = '$setor',locais = '$locais', motivo = '$motivo', enviando = '$enviando', recebendo = '$recebendo', defeito = '$defeito', uldefeito = '$uldefeito', transporte = '$transporte', dataid = '$dataid', dataret = '$dataret', login = '$login', status_eqp = '$status_eqp', arquivo= '$novo_nome' WHERE codigo= '$codigo' "; 

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

if($consulta){
    
echo ("<h1>Dados alterados com sucesso</h1>");
    
} else {
    
    echo ("<h1>Erro inesperado</h1>". mysqli_error());
}

mysqli_close($conexao);

?>

<!doctype html> 

<html lang ="pt-br">          <!define a linguagem da pagina>                   <!input type="text"> <!para inserir um campo e o tipo>

  <head>                      <!informações do cabeçelho>

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../formularios_rictv/css/css_tela_salvar.css">

  </head>


      <body>

         <div class="container">

          <nav>

           <ul class="menu">

                  <li></li>
                    <a href="inicio.php"><li>Serviços</li></a>
                 <a href="cons.php"><li>Consulta</li></a>
                  <a href="../equipamentos/inicio.php"><li>Equipamentos</li></a>

                </ul>

                    </nav>

           <section>
```

**vlww**